# Is it secure to access web with Xubuntu in VirtualBox running in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, web-browser

Support for Windows XP is ending soon. Therefore, I am seeking a secure solution to continue with Windows XP.

When I access the web from Xubuntu in VirtualBox running in Windows XP, is the Windows XP environment secure? And if not, how can I make it more secure?

**EDIT:** I am asking for a level of security for everyday use  - e.g. Firefox or Chrome, reading blogs, viewing emails, Youtube etc. I try to avoid shadier sites like porn sites, executing files from unknown sources etc.

Comment: Secure against what? And what do you plan on doing on the Internet?

Comment: @TildalWave: Normal everyday use firefox or chrome, reading blogs, viewing emails, youtube etc. no advanced things.

Comment: Please [edit] these details into your question, comments should be considered transient here with emphasis on questions and their answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mostly fine, but you have to consider a few things.

Firstly, the virtual machine accesses the internet presumably via the host, meaning the host has internet connectivity. This must be suitably firewalled, preferably relying on an external hardware firewall as exploits may be found in the XP (SP3) firewall that won't be patched.

You will probably need anti-virus running on the host machine if you are downloading files in the virtual machine that become readable/executable by the host.

If malware ever infects xubuntu, and this exploit can defeat the hyper-visor provided by virtualbox *and* then has the ability to infect an XP machine, then of course you'll be infected that way, although this is a rather convoluted and unlikely attack vector. Plus this could still be mitigated by anti-virus running on the XP machine that may prevent exploits even if OS patches aren't provided for them. This is because some anti-virus vendors will continue to create signatures for malware affecting Windows XP, in addition to heuristics.

Comment: OP can bridge the VM to the host NIC, and block all host connectivity by MAC in the LAN router. See http://www.actuarialoutpost.com/actuarial_discussion_forum/showthread.php?t=221881 for example.

Comment: @mirimir This is a good option and recommended setup, although your XP machine will still need to be protected from LAN threats.

Answer (score 0):

XP is dead now.. So this is what I recommend:

Never go online with XP and don't plug anything new/untrusted into that box again. Don't trust ANY software to help XP go online. Just during 1 session with XP online, it could infect your router, your memory, boot manager, bios and rip any passes you enter. It doesn't matter if you reboot with a fresh copy (VM or whatever) as it can just get infected again at boot.

If you must go online with that old box, install *Linux Lite *with* XP. Boot into Linux Lite to go online. Remember to unplug router before you boot back into XP. But I wouldn't even risk doing that as malware can jump from Linux to XP at boot, and you may never know it. Better to use XP alone and stay offline, or completely replace it with Linux Lite, or Win 7 if you can.

**Note that Linux Lite is the best Ubuntu based distro for older, slower PCs (right now) and has Long Term Support (LTS) into 2017. Mint has an LTS Lite but it was buggy and not fixed (yet). Zorin 6.2 Lite was good but it's now out of date. Thus, Linux Lite takes the cake:
https://www.linuxliteos.com/

That all said, If you can upgrade, go with Windows 7. Most all of my XP apps work fine in Windows 7 32 bit. All you may need is to install some more memory, but it sounds like you have enough if you can run a VM. All you need is 1GB, but at least 2GB is best. ReadyBoost on a thumb drive may help speed some things up too.

Answer (score 0):

You could/should reverse the situation, with Xubuntu as host, XP as client. I use Ubuntu as desktop, but sometimes need XP for Photoshop. Then I start up virtualbox, and use XP with the LAN connection disabled. This way, XP cannot connect to the internet, and you can still use it for those apps that only run under Windows. You could do the same with 7, but that will require a lot more power and RAM. When shutting down I always revert to the last snapshot.

If you need XP to go online, you can use a copy of the VM to go online, and revert to the last snapshot afterwards.